# WDS 2012: UEFI Client PXE Boot ends in BSOD: UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME

Tags: pxe-boot, wds, unattended, uefi

When I try to boot my uefi client from LAN it successfully downloads boot.wim from my WDS 2012, shows the Windows Logo for some seconds, but then it crashes, showing BSOD and the message "UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME".
I'm using the same x64 boot.wim as with the BIOS clients, but with the mbr clients it does work.
What is it, that makes my boot.wim unusable for uefi clients?

Comment: Some questions come to mind: Do you have enough RAM on the clients to boot the x64 image, how did you build the boot image?

Comment: 8gb RAM, the boot.wim comes from a windows 8.1 DVD - the same boot.wim works when I switch the client from uefi to legacy mode. I used the same boot.wim to build a WinPE USB Stick. When I boot from that stick, I can start the install, but installation fails becaus of missing drivers. But the image seems to be mountable however...

Comment: Ok, what drivers are missing? Also is your bios/uefi up to date? Are you able to uefi boot other computers?

Comment: I injected all the drivers I could find into my boot.wim and I also installed latest bios update but no avail. I can install the same uefi client with a dvd and that works.

Comment: I tried the following:
I made a WinPE bootable USB-Stick with ADK 8.1, booted my PC from that stick in UEFI mode, and it worked.
Then I took the boot.wim from my WinPE Stick and loaded it as an additional boot image on WDS. When I pxe-boot my UEFI client from that boot.wim coming from adk, I get the unmountable_boot_volume error again.
Then I thought, maybe some drivers are missing, and I injected all the device drivers I could find into my boot.wim, but that would not make a difference.

Comment: Did you try using a different computer (different hardware set)?

Comment: Yes I did, but only HP. Notebook, Desktop, SSD, HD.

Comment: Did the same thing happen to the notebook and desktop?

Comment: What are you trying to deploy?

Comment: same thing happens with nb and dt, with ssd and hdd. trying to deploy windows 8.1 x64

Comment: Have you tried using mdt, did you check the hashes for the source install disk and did you try using the driver feature of wds? Some of these questions are also like suggestions for better practices if you generally do not follow them...

Comment: I just tried it with mdt and got the same result.
Everything works no problem as soon as I switch the client to bios.

Comment: Have you considered booting with BIOS then deploying a UEFI configuration? Can you get to the boot loader menu in UEFI mode? Is Secure Boot enabled?

Comment: I tried pxe booting in bios mode and deploying the uefi stuff - this does not work.
When I try to pxe boot in uefi i can select the boot loader.
bsod appears after succesful download of boot.wim
secure boot is not enabled

Comment: When you say `this does not work` are you referring to the deployment type? If so then it is possible. Try to add more images to the BIOS loader and see if you can get a selectable menu.

Comment: I added different boot.wims but no avail. Could it be there is something wrong with the .bcd which is generated by the wds-server?

Comment: That is a good idea, See if you can regenerate the BCD files. Tell me how it goes.